# ggplot custom x-axis (Month) is compressed / not using whole range

Tags: r, ggplot2, boxplot, scaling

I'm trying to create a boxplot based on timeseries data. Problem is the data appears to be "compressed" in width and does not cover the range it is supposed to cover. My x-axis is the month of observation, but in a custom order (November to March). The plot only covers December to February, but I definitely have observations for November and March.

```
level_order <- c('November', 'December', 'January', 'February', 'March')
plot <- ggplot(data = df, aes(y = y, x = factor(Month,level = level_order), group=DAP)) +
geom_boxplot(fill="grey85", width = 2.0) +
scale_x_discrete(limits = level_order)
plot
```

Result: X-Axis range is correct, and all entries are there - but somehow compressed in width ...
[image: boxplot]

and here a sample of the dataset

```
> df
    DAP Date       Month    y
1    47 2010-11-26 November 0.6872708
16   99 2011-01-17  January 0.7929280
31  151 2011-03-10    March 0.6915378
46   85 2012-01-03  January 0.7346495
61  137 2012-02-24 February 0.7178306
76   75 2012-12-24 December 0.7287693
91  127 2013-02-14 February 0.7282626
```

Comment: Can you check again after removing `group=DAP` ? It looks like this doesn't allow you to have multiple observations per month, in order to get a proper boxplot.

Comment: Could you apply a `dput(df)`, please.

Comment: Remove the `width` argument.

Comment: @stefan is right. Was just about to add that answer until I saw their comment. Care to answer @stefan?

Comment: Hi @duckmyer. Feel free to post your answer. That's fine for me.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your issue is that I do not think the `width` argument does what you think it does. Consider what occurs without the `width` argument:

```
plot <- ggplot(data = df, aes(y = y, x = Month, group = DAP)) +
    geom_boxplot(fill = "grey85") +
    scale_x_discrete(limits = level_order)
plot
```

[image]

This is what I think you want.

Comment: Thank you, setting the width was indeed the issue! However, next issue that shows up is that the boxplots should be more left or right oriented depending on the day of month. Kind of like using the complete date (day + month) for the x-axis,  but I really only want to display the Month on the x-axis. Might have to open a new question for that I guess

Comment: @Alwin Yeah, in this case I think a new question would be the way to go. In particular, usually I'd suggest just using your actual `Date` variable and using `scale_x_date()` to govern how the x axis appears. However, in this case, you're wanting to group months across years, so that doesn't quite work out.... so probably a new question with a fully developed statement of that issue would be the easiest way to get a good solution for you.